# Get variable from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to access the variable `boolean is_connected;` in Broadcast Receiver from my main_activity. How do I make this happen?

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
boolean is_connected;
MediaPlayer media;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
        media=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.battery);
        media.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        is_connected=false;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where does your BroadcastReceiver reside? Is it an inner class of your activity, or is it a stand alone receiver which is registered in the manifest?

Comment: stand alone with registration in manifest.

Comment: Do you want your main activity to be alerted when the power is connected/disconnected or do you want to be able to see if the power is connected/disconnected when you open your main activity?

Comment: @DavidZafrani I want to be able to see if the power is connected/disconnected

Comment: @MichaelPrechtel: In that case, why don't you add the receiver as an inner class of your activity?

Comment: How would I do that? I tried it, but it does not work automatically when disconnecting from the charger.

Comment: @MichaelPrechtel I've added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26596704/1214974) in which I attempt to explain how to do this. Remember to register the receiver in onResume and remove it in onPause. Also this (obviously) only works when your activity is in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One, you can put MyServiceStartReceiver in MyActivity and create the variable as a class variable in MainActivity. (See how I have implemented that receiver that will receive your custom intent broadcast below).

Or you can keep your MyServiceStartReceiver separate, allowing you to use it across your application, and send out a broadcast when it is done with it's onReceive function and needs to send out it's boolean result.

**STEPS**

In your MyServiceStartReceiver class create the variable

```
public static final String CONNECTED_KEY = "connected";
```

Then at the end of onReceive() when you are ready to let your Activity know what the boolean is

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction(MainActivity.CONNECTION_BROADCAST_ACTION);
broadcast.putExtra(CONNECTED_KEY, is_connected);
sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

In MainActivity, you can create a custom broadcast receiver. That receiver can be something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public static final String CONNECTION_BROADCAST_ACTION = "my.package.name.CONNECTION_BROADCAST";
    protected boolean isConnected = false;
    private ConnectionStatusReceiver statusReceiver;

    // Your MainActivity stuff you have now and add

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume(); 
        if(statusReceiver == null)
            statusReceiver = new ConnectionStatusReceiver();
        registerReceiver(statusReceiver, new IntentFilter(CONNECTION_BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(statusReceiver);
    } 

    public class ConnectionStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        // override the onReceive method and in it
        isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(BroadcastingClass.CONNECTED_KEY, false);
        // do what you want with it
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it, but if you have any issues let me know.

Comment: to be honest, I don't get exactly how I can achieve that... I attached my code. I want to make is_connected=false and send it to my main_activity when the power is disconnected.

Comment: @MichaelPrechtel in onReceive when you set your value to false send a new broadcast to a receiver that you have built in main_activity to receive your broadcast. You should also use java naming conventions where variables get lowere camel case (isConnected) and classes get upper camel case (MainActivity).

Comment: I really don't get it.
`public static final String CONNECTED_KEY = "connected";` --> in MyStartServiceReceiver
`Intent broadcast = new Intent("my.broadcast.action.ACTION");
broadcast.putExtra(CONNECTED_KEY, is_connected); // add this
sendBroadcast(broadcast);` --> in onReceive()
`boolean isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(BroadcastingClass.CONNECTED_KEY, false);` --> in Main_activity?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you simply want to react (in your activity) to changes to the power state. My suggestion is to declare a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
  private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)     {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        // do stuff
      } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
        // do other stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, remember to register and remove the receiver in `onResume` and `onPause`, respectively.

As `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a *sticky broadcast*, you will receive (through the return value of the register call) the most recent intent when you register your receiver. This is helpful if you want to init your activity according to this value (this would be in your `onResume` implementation).

Also, be aware that you should not be able to use your current strategy (i.e. using a standalone receiver registered in the manifest) for this type of broadcast. See the documentation for the broadcast action [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).